# Calculate a Hexagon based on a point

Tags: java, geometry, coordinates, geography, rotational-matrices

this is my problem:

I need to determine the correct coordinates(Latitude,Longitude) of a hexagon/polygon.
I have as inputs:

- latitude (double)
- longitude (double)
- radius (of the circle) (int)

The steps taken:

1. Given point is translated with the length of the radius, obtaining the first point: lat = lat + radius
2. New coordinates are obtained (rad is the angle theta in radians)

   **result.x = Math.cos(rad) * lat + Math.sin(rad) * lon;

   result.y = Math.cos(rad) * lon - Math.sin(rad) * lat ;**

Problem: Setting the radius to 1 returns me a huge result, a way too bigger hexagon than i want (in the sense that the are contained is almost the entire globe :( ), can anyone englighten me with why this happens and how could i fix it?

[all code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgGui.jpg)

[and here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1xo7.jpg)
as you can see, for the input -71.24 43.06 I'm getting a vertice with coordinates 2 83, which is huge

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaG4U.jpg)

Comment: 1. You should post code, there's no way we can guess what is happening from just a description.  Also show the inputs you use, what the result is and what result you were expecting.  2. You said "globe."  Are these points on the surface of a sphere?  Is the radius the distance over the surface of a sphere or does the radius intersect the surface?  Can you be more descriptive in general what exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't see the radius in the formula

Comment: [Mandatory reading](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/)

Comment: Also, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @c0der added photos

Comment: Please post the correct formula and [mre] of your code

Comment: @0x5453 i agree with the post, but since this is merely an implementation bug for a short formula and not some lost pointer in a huge project, I don't think is that big of a fuss :)

Comment: @c0der i am not sure this is the correct formula because of these results! this is the correct formula if you want to rotate a vector using a rotation matrix in Cartesian space, but i believe I'm having problems because I'm working with latitude and longitude

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have the correct formula and you have a coding problem, post your code. If it is math question ask [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I needed that as well on a flutter project, after some research I found out [turf.js destination method](https://turfjs.org/docs/#destination)

By using it, you can get the 6 points of the hexagon around a center point, based on a certain radius:

```
Point center = Point(coordinates: Position(latitude, longitude)); // Your center point

Point p1 = destination(center, radius, 0, Unit.meters); // top
Point p2 = destination(center, radius, 60, Unit.meters); // top left
Point p3 = destination(center, radius, 120, Unit.meters);  // bottom left
Point p4 = destination(center, radius, 180, Unit.meters); // bottom
Point p5 = destination(center, radius, 240, Unit.meters); // bottom right
Point p6 = destination(center, radius, 300, Unit.meters); // top right
```

Not sure about this, but Turf seems to be porting to Java as well [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/guides/turf/)